# Sql - Different results in the recursive part in Oracle 21c

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, recursive-query

Thank you very much for all the solutions you offer because when time permits I go to the site and try to solve it myself so in this way I also learn.

I use both Sql Server 2022 and Oracle 21c.

Every time I find an interesting problem if the solution offered is only for Sql Server, I try to adapt it to Oracle and vice versa.

Now I need your help, please, to solve a problem, but especially to understand because unfortunately in this case I don't understand what else I should do to have the same solution in Oracle.

I left from the following problem
[SQL Server - Checking for integer (id) within hierarchy of ids](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76673632/sql-server-checking-for-integer-id-within-hierarchy-of-ids)
posted a few days ago and where the solution was in Sql Server.

Unfortunately, after I adapted to Oracle in some places I do not get the same results.

Without any changes to the script and ordering asc by location_id everything is correct up to location_id 6 including location_id=6 then everything is wrong.

In the recurrent part I modified and put partition by tree1.location_order in that row_number, the results are ok except for location_id=10
I kept trying to change, but to solve for location_id =10, I ordered in the recursive part by tree1.location_id desc.
It is solved with location_id = 10, but it appears wrongly at location_id = 6 and everything is already getting confusing.
I am convinced that the solution lies in the recursive ordering of row_number.

I can't connect the information somehow, understand logically what is happening behind (I don't have much experience)
and to visualize that ordering from row_number --order by b.location_order ,tree1.location_id

I also added that RNPROB thinking that maybe I will understand better.

I created both db fiddle for Sql Server 2022 https://dbfiddle.uk/r-QXHGJJ with the desired output and db fiddle for Oracle https://dbfiddle.uk/tRhdk0X3
(here, unfortunately, the db fiddle insert part gives an error, but in oracle it works fine)

Thank you

Desired output.In the fiddle is properly ordered the desired output.
I appoligize for how it looks below.

```
location_id parent_id   level   location_order  location_name   location_name_hierarchy row_number_hierarchy    location_id_hierarchy
1   NULL    0   1   Location 1  Location 1  1   1
2   1   1   2   Location 2  Location 1/Location 2   1/2 1/2
3   1   1   1   Location 3  Location 1/Location 3   1/1 1/3
4   1   1   3   Location 4  Location 1/Location 4   1/3 1/4
5   2   2   1   Location 5  Location 1/Location 2/Location 5    1/2/1   1/2/5
6   5   3   1   Location 6  Location 1/Location 2/Location 5/Location 6 1/2/1/1 1/2/5/6
7   2   2   2   Location 7  Location 1/Location 2/Location 7    1/2/2   1/2/7
8   7   3   1   Location 8  Location 1/Location 2/Location 7/Location 8 1/2/2/1 1/2/7/8
9   3   2   1   Location 9  Location 1/Location 3/Location 9    1/1/1   1/3/9
10  9   3   1   Location 10 Location 1/Location 3/Location 9/Location 10    1/1/1/1 1/3/9/10
11  4   2   2   Location 11 Location 1/Location 4/Location 11   1/3/2   1/4/11
12  4   2   1   Location 12 Location 1/Location 4/Location 12   1/3/1   1/4/12
```

Comment: @OldProgrammer Thank you very much for editing my question. Can you please tell me how to edit it correctly so that I know for the next questions?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```sql
row_number() over (partition by b.parent_id order by  b.location_order, b.location_id)
```

Which would make your query:

```sql
with tree1 (
  location_id,
  parent_id,
  nivel,
  location_order,
  location_name,
  location_name_hierarchy,
  row_number_hierarchy, 
  RNPROB,
  location_id_hierarchy
) AS (
  SELECT location_id,
         parent_id,
         0 AS nivel,
         location_order,
         location_name,
         cast(location_name as nvarchar2(200)),
         cast(
           row_number() over (
             partition by location_order
             order by location_order, location_id
           )
           as nvarchar2(200)
         ),
         row_number() over (
           partition by location_order
           order by location_order, location_id
         ),
         cast(location_id as nvarchar2(200))
  FROM   location_tbl
  WHERE  parent_id IS NULL 
UNION ALL
  SELECT B.location_id,
         B.parent_id,
         tree1.nivel + 1,
         B.location_order,
         B.location_name,
         location_name_hierarchy || '/' || cast(B.location_name as nvarchar2(200)), 
         row_number_hierarchy || '/' || row_number() over (
           partition by b.parent_id
           order by  b.location_order, b.location_id
         ),
         row_number() over (
           partition by b.parent_id
           order by b.location_order, b.location_id
         ),
         location_id_hierarchy || '/' || cast(B.location_id as nvarchar2(200))
  FROM   location_tbl  B 
         INNER JOIN tree1
         ON tree1.location_id = B.parent_id
)
SELECT location_id,
       parent_id,
       NIVEL,
       location_order,
       location_name,
       location_name_hierarchy,
       row_number_hierarchy,
       RNPROB,
       location_id_hierarchy
FROM   tree1
order by location_id;
```

Which outputs:

| LOCATION_ID | PARENT_ID | NIVEL | LOCATION_ORDER | LOCATION_NAME | LOCATION_NAME_HIERARCHY | ROW_NUMBER_HIERARCHY | RNPROB | LOCATION_ID_HIERARCHY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | 0 | 1 | Location 1 | Location 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2 | Location 2 | Location 1/Location 2 | 1/2 | 2 | 1/2 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | Location 3 | Location 1/Location 3 | 1/1 | 1 | 1/3 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 3 | Location 4 | Location 1/Location 4 | 1/3 | 3 | 1/4 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 1 | Location 5 | Location 1/Location 2/Location 5 | 1/2/1 | 1 | 1/2/5 |
| 6 | 5 | 3 | 1 | Location 6 | Location 1/Location 2/Location 5/Location 6 | 1/2/1/1 | 1 | 1/2/5/6 |
| 7 | 2 | 2 | 2 | Location 7 | Location 1/Location 2/Location 7 | 1/2/2 | 2 | 1/2/7 |
| 8 | 7 | 3 | 1 | Location 8 | Location 1/Location 2/Location 7/Location 8 | 1/2/2/1 | 1 | 1/2/7/8 |
| 9 | 3 | 2 | 1 | Location 9 | Location 1/Location 3/Location 9 | 1/1/1 | 1 | 1/3/9 |
| 10 | 9 | 3 | 1 | Location 10 | Location 1/Location 3/Location 9/Location 10 | 1/1/1/1 | 1 | 1/3/9/10 |
| 11 | 4 | 2 | 2 | Location 11 | Location 1/Location 4/Location 11 | 1/3/2 | 2 | 1/4/11 |
| 12 | 4 | 2 | 1 | Location 12 | Location 1/Location 4/Location 12 | 1/3/1 | 1 | 1/4/12 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xDwFMJ9w)

Comment: MT0 thank you for taking time and answer my question.
can you please help me if you have the time to understand logic the answer?
why partition by b.parent__id and not on tree1.location_order.
So we take the row where parent_id is null and join with the part of recursive query row by row.
Thank you once again,
Your answer give the right results and i will vote for him like always for your answers.

Comment: @Florin The results you appear to want is to get the row number of each child and restart the ordering for each path and, given that your hierarchy is a tree structure without back or cross edges) then the path can be uniquely identified by the parent.